# Bash making a new file with same name but lowercases

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a problem, for an assignment I have to open a file and use the `sed` command to change some stuff and then put the output into a new file. The changing part was not the hardest but writing/copying the output into the new file is the problem. Lets say my beginning file is called `ABC1d.gb` and the output file has to be called `abc1d.gb`, when i try this with `>` or `>>` it will or overwrite the beginning file and empty it or it will append the output to the `ABC1d.gb` file. So i want to know if i can even make a file `abc1d.gb` and if so can i also aply it to my assignment?

Thanks in advance!

My code line that I use now is:

```
cat ABC1d.gb | sed 's/ABC/abc/g' > abc1d.gb
```

EDIT/UPDATE:
The problem is my system, I have made the folder i was workin in casesensitive via windowscommands and now it does like it should. The problem wasn't the code, it was the system/folder...

Comment: It sounds like you're using a case-insensitive filesystem, so `ABC1d.gb` and `abc1d.gb` are the same file.

Comment: If you're running this on Ubuntu as your tag implies, the command you show shouldn't be changing `ABC1d.gb` at all. Are you sure about those details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command will only have a problem if `ABC1d.gb` and `abc1d.gb` are the same file, which will happen if you're using a case-insensitive filesystem.

The solution is to write to a temporary file and then rename it.

```
sed 's/ABC/abc/g' ABC1d.gb > abc1d.temp
mv abc1d.temp abc1d.gb
```

Comment: Yea i tought about that, but one problem is (wich i probably should have mentioned) is that it has to be 1 commandline.

Comment: Unix doesn't usually use case-insensitive filesystems. Why are you doing this exercise on that type of filesystem?

Comment: I would not know..... my teacher wants us to do it like this but we have never even used tee before so thats the strange part

Comment: As I said in another comment, `tee` is not a guarantee to solve the problem. You can't read and write the same file in a single command.